# Python Tkinter window not opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, bots

I made a program that is a bot in python that responds to your commands you say. It uses google speech recognition. I wanted to make a gui with tkinter for it, but the tkinter window is not opening when I run the program. the tkinter program should display your own message and the response of the bot in the window. This is my code

```
from cgitb import text
from multiprocessing.connection import answer_challenge
from turtle import goto
from typing import Text
from urllib import response
import speech_recognition as sr 
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
import pyttsx3
import pyjokes
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
import random
import os
import wikipedia
from google_trans_new import google_translator
import webbrowser
import pywhatkit
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue



googlenews = GoogleNews()
engine=pyttsx3.init()
voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice',voices[2].id)
recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
q = Queue()
root = Tk()
root.title("Gideon")

BG_GRAY = "#ABB2B9"
BG_COLOR = "#17202A"
TEXT_COLOR = "#EAECEE"

FONT = "Helvetica 14"
FONT_BOLD = "Helvetica 13 bold"





def resources():
    print("heating up the program")
    googlenews = GoogleNews()
    engine=pyttsx3.init()
    voices=engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice',voices[2].id)
    recognizer=sr.Recognizer()
    startup()

def startup():
    name = os.getlogin()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("Clearing background noises")
            recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source,duration=5)
    sentences = "Hello i am gideon", f"How can i be of service {name}", f"hello {name}", f"We did not speak for a while {name}"
    opening = random.choice(sentences)
    engine.say(opening)
    engine.runAndWait()
    print("started up")
    listen()
    
    

def listen():
    name = os.getlogin()
    a = "b"
    print("listening")
    

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
            try:
                recordedaudio=recognizer.listen(source, timeout= 99999)
                print("recorded audio")
            except:
                pass 
            
            
    try:
            
            text=recognizer.recognize_google(recordedaudio,language='en_US')
            text=text.lower()
            if "gideon" in text:
                text = text.replace("gideon", "")
                print('Your message:',format(text))
                
            else:
                print("did not match")
                listen()
            

    
            
            if "joke" in text:
                joke = pyjokes.get_joke(language="en", category="neutral")
                print(joke)
                botResponse = joke
                engine.say(joke)
                engine.runAndWait()
                
            if "how are you" in text:
                snt = f"Good as long as my script is up to date and running", "Im doing fine", "as long as you are doing great im doing great"
                snt = random.choice(snt)
                botResponse = snt
                engine.say(snt)
                engine.runAndWait()
                
            if "wikipedia" in text:
                search=wikipedia.summary(text)
                engine.say(search)
                engine.runAndWait()
                botResponse = search
                
        
            if "browser" in text:
                a='Opening your internetbrowser.'
                engine.say(a)
                botResponse = a
                engine.runAndWait()
                webbrowser.open(url="https://duckduckgo.com")
            if 'time' in text:
                time = datetime.now().strftime('%I:%M %p')
                print(time)
                botResponse = time
                engine.say(time)
                engine.runAndWait()
            if 'play' in text:
                a='opening youtube..'
                botResponse = a
                engine.say(a)
                engine.runAndWait()
                pywhatkit.playonyt(text)
            if 'news' in text:
                print('Getting news ')
                googlenews.get_news('Today news')
                googlenews.result()
                a=googlenews.gettext()
                botResponse = a
                engine.say(botResponse)
                engine.runAndWait()
            
            send = "You -> " + text.get()
            txt.insert(END, "\n" + send)
            txt.insert(END, "\n" + f"Bot -> {botResponse}")

           
            listen() 
    except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
            listen()


lable1 = Label(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, text="Welcome", font=FONT_BOLD, pady=10, width=20, height=1).grid(
    row=0)

txt = Text(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=FONT, width=60)
txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(txt)
scrollbar.place(relheight=1, relx=0.974)





resources()

root.mainloop()
```

Does anyone know the solution to this problem please let me know!

Comment: This code is generating a lot of import warnings. You have several unused imports, and `datetime` is imported twice. Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). *minimal* being the key word. There are also more than a few unused variables and redeclarations...

Comment: Try to give the Tkinter window a size. ```root.geometry('300x200')```.

Comment: @Nili that did not work, still does not open the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your program from a tkinter-centric point of view, it doesn't have a chance to bring up the interface until/unless everything else in the program works.  It might be better to bring up the interface and then fire off the body of the program.  This could be a button, but I'll use a timer below and simulate the remainder of the program running with a `sleep()`:

```
from tkinter import *

BG_COLOR = "#17202A"
TEXT_COLOR = "#EAECEE"

FONT = "Helvetica 14"
FONT_BOLD = "Helvetica 13 bold"

def resources():
    # simulate resources()
    from time import sleep
    sleep(10)

    txt.insert(END, " ready!\n")

root = Tk()
root.title("Gideon")

Label(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, text="Welcome", font=FONT_BOLD, pady=10, width=20, height=1).grid(row=0)

txt = Text(root, bg=BG_COLOR, fg=TEXT_COLOR, font=FONT, width=60)
txt.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=txt.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ns")

txt.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

root.after(1000, resources)

txt.insert(END, "Starting up ...")

root.mainloop()
```

I also reworked your scroll bar as I'm not convinced your code was working and I was uncertain about the mixing and matching of `grid` and `place`.  What you did may be fine, but I added a different approach that I was able to confirm is working.